# responseText always returns 'undefined' even though Im using asynchrous 'success' trigger

Tags: ajax, jquery

```
function WyslijRequestAjaxem(){         
            var pole1 = document.getElementById("data_albo_czas");
            var url1 = "date_time_now.php";         
            alert(pole1.value);
            alert("xd");
                $.ajax({
                    url: url1,
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "html",
                    data: { zmienna: pole1.value},
                    success: OdbierzResponse                            
                })
        }

        function OdbierzResponse(response) {
            var p = document.getElementById("pt1");             
            p.innerHTML = response.responseText;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function WyslijRequestAjaxem() {
    var pole1 = document.getElementById("data_albo_czas");
    var url1 = "date_time_now.php";
    alert(pole1.value);
    alert("xd");
    $.ajax({
        url: url1,
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        data: {
            zmienna: pole1.value
        },
        success: function (response) {
            OdbierzResponse(response); // call OdbierzResponse function with parameter here
        }
    })
}
```

Try change

```
p.innerHTML = response.responseText;
```

to

```
p.innerHTML = response;
```

Comment: It's still undefinied

Comment: @Patryk Try change `p.innerHTML = response.responseText;` to `p.innerHTML = response;`

Comment: Thanks, it works now :) all my code was OK, just that response.responseText thingy... please edit ur answer so I can accept it as a best one

Answer (score 3):

In the case of a html `dataType` for jQuery's AJAX function, the first argument passed to the `success` callback **is** the responseText, so change your function to:

```
function OdbierzResponse(response) {
    var p = document.getElementById("pt1");             
    p.innerHTML = response;
}
```

As explained in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) this function is passed three arguments:

> The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

If you need the actual jqXhr object to work with you'd need to do:

```
function OdbierzResponse(response, status, xhr) {
    var p = document.getElementById("pt1");             
    p.innerHTML = response;
    ...
}
```

and use `xhr` to access the properties or methods that you require.